# How to correctly work with docker on a very basic level?

Tags: docker

I'm using Docker for Windows (Education Edition with Hyper-V) and am fairly new to Docker. My workflow feels a little bit complicated and I think there are better ways. Here's what I do:

When I develop with Docker containers, I add a `Dockerfile` to my project first.

Then I am going to build the container by running a command like `docker build -t containername .`

When Docker is done building, I am going to run the container with a command like `docker run -p 8080:8080 containername` (sometimes I add a volume at this point)

This runs the container and leaves my Powershell in a state where I can read debug messages and so on from the container.

Then I'm testing and developing the application.

Once I'm done developing and testing, I need to CTRL + C in order to exit the running container.

Now comes the tricky part: Say, I forgot something and want to test what I forgot to test right away. I would again run `docker build -t containername .` **BUT** docker would now tell me, that the port is already taken. So I continue like this:

I search for my container with this command: `docker ps`

Once I found the name (i.e. `silly_walrusbeard`) I type `docker stop silly_walrusbeard`. Now I can run `docker build -t containername .` again and the port is now free.

How could I simplify this workflow? Is there an alternative to CTRL+C that also stops the container? Thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: If I'm actively iterating on my code, I tend to do it outside Docker for less of this sort of friction.  You might `docker run` your image with a consistent `--name` so that it's easier to `docker rm` later (saves the `docker ps` step).  You also can use Docker Compose here; re-running `docker-compose up` will recreate an existing container if it needs to and has all of the container options written down in the YAML file.

Comment: Thanks for the `--name` suggestion! That's great and a good improvement to my workflow! I will also consider using `docker-compose` it just seem "too much" for me for the beginning but it might be the better solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

list all current containers with `docker ps -a`. Kill them with `docker kill <ID>` and maybe `docker rm <ID>`.

And when you run new containers use the `--rm` to free ports (among other things) automatically when the container stops:

```
docker run --rm -it containername
```

(I usually need the `-it` when running shells, but I'm not sure about powershell. Maybe you don't need it)

Comment: my default command when writing dockerfiles is (in bash): `docker build -t abc . && docker run -it --rm abc`. This takes care of pretty much everything, while not being overly complicated, yet highly adaptable.  Also I need only to press two buttons to run it ("up" and "enter")

Comment: If I understand that correctly, Running `docker run` with `--rm` and `--it` removes the need for `docker ps` and `docker stop`?

Comment: @NitricWare yes